# PHP print output of foreach to screen, for each item by ajax (as progress bar and show online process!)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, foreach

I recently ask same question but I think it was too hard.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659295/

So I change it to a simple version:

I have a php code:

```
function callafunction($count){
...do something....
return count;
} 

$count=0;
foreach($rows as $row)
{
echo "<div>";
echo callafunction(++$count);// this function maybe need 10 or more second to proccess
echo "<div>";
}
```

how can I print results in a html page with each loop of foreach by ajax?
is it possible?

For example:

```
<!-- First Append div without refresh page -->
<div> 1 </div>   // new row
.
.
.
<!-- second Append div without refresh page -->
<div> 1 </div>        // old row
**<div> 2 </div>**    // new row
.
.
.<!-- third Append div without refresh page -->
<div> 1 </div>     //  old row
<div> 2 </div>     //  old row
**<div> 3 </div>** // new row
```

Comment: Your code should work. Do you want to implement AJAX now?

Comment: Yes, I know it works. But I want for each loop, the result print  dynamically...I hope u underestand me :)

Comment: are you using jquery?  You could append new divs with 'after' and give each div a new id; or use innerhtml if you're not using jquery.

Comment: So you want to call the page with AJAX to print each loop one by one, or you want to print them all together? (even though with AJAX)

Comment: yes Exactly I want to call the page with AJAX to print each loop one by one (Not all together after finish loop!)

Comment: Maybe call "jquery append after" with function (not clicking)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your AJAX endpoint in PHP, and call it and update the DOM using JQuery. PHP is not capable of doing so after page load. The trick is to include a `callback` parameter to your `callafunction()` function. In your case, `callafunction()` would initiate an AJAX request to a PHP page that produces the data you need. When the data is ready, you get to call your callack (here I called it `writeData()`).

```js
function callafunction($count,cb){
  //  do an AJAX request to a PHP file
  //  here i am just mocking it by firing the callback after 1 second
  window.setInterval( function(){
   var mockResult = 'The result for row ' + $count + ' is: ' + Math.random().toString(16);
    cb(mockResult);
  }, 1000 );
}

// the function to write the data once AJAX has returned it
var writeData = function(div,result) {
  div.html(result);
};

$('.row').each(function(){
   var $thisRow = $(this);
   // call the function, which then calls itself every x seconds
   callafunction( $(this).data('rowId'), writeData.bind(null,$thisRow) );   
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 200px;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- created by a PHP loop -->
<div class="row" data-row-id="1"></div>
<div class="row" data-row-id="2"></div>
<div class="row" data-row-id="3"></div>
```

Comment: It would be difficult for me to post the PHP code you need, because I don't know anything about your app